# Conflict with Android RadioGroup and tabular layout

Tags: android, radio-button, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout, android-radiogroup

I am working on a GUI that is defined by data from a webservice. One aspect is that I have a table structure of 2 columns and n rows. In the left column there are RadioButtons, in the right column EditText widgets. All the RadioButtons are logically member of a RadioGroup. But here is the problem: you can't add a RadioButton both to a RadioGroup and a container structure like LinearLayout or TableLayout.

Does anybody have a suggestion how I can keep my 2 column table structure and at the same time have the RadioButtons being a member of a Radiogroup and as such enforce single select?

Thanks in advance for any helpful suggestion.